# REST API Multiple PUT or DELETE in one time

Tags: rest, api-design, restful-url, http-verbs

Greeting everyone, I have a datatable in my html page that I populated using REST API. I can create new row and also update or delete by selecting a row and clicking the edit or delete button.

But currently I am unable to delete update or delete multiple row at once due to url error,

e.g : `PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/content_detail/5,7,9/ 404 (Not Found)`

how can I split this this into several separate url with respective id when I update or delete.

e.g :

```
/dashboard/content_detail/5
/dashboard/content_detail/7
/dashboard/content_detail/9
```

Below is my code, any help is much appreciated thank you.

```
    idSrc: 'id',
    ajax: {
        create: {
            type: 'POST',
            url: content_path,
            data: function (content_data) {
                var create_data = {};
                $.each(content_data.data, function (id, value) {
                    create_data['name'] = value['name'];
                    create_data['description'] = value['description'];
                    create_data['category'] = value['category'];
                });
                return create_data;
            },
            success: function () {
                content_table.api().ajax.reload();
            }
        },
        edit: {
            type: 'PUT',
            url: '/dashboard/content_detail/_id_/',
            data: function (content_data) {
                var updated_data = {};
                $.each(content_data.data, function (id, value) {
                    updated_data['description'] = value['description'];
                    updated_data['category'] = value['category'];
                    updated_data['name'] = value['name'];
                });
                return updated_data;
            },

            success: function () {
                content_table.api().ajax.reload();
            }
        },
        remove: {
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: '/dashboard/content_detail/_id_/',
            data: function (content_data) {
                var deleted_data = {};
                $.each(content_data.data, function (id, value) {
                    deleted_data['id'] = id;
                });
                return deleted_data;
            },
            success: function () {
                content_table.api().ajax.reload();
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: is it a design or programming question?

Comment: Its a programming question, I'm asking how to PUT individual url rather than something like this `/dashboard/content_detail/5,7,9/` which will create an error

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to allow the update of a large number of items at once, then `PATCH` might be your friend:

Looking at the [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) (which defines the Patch standard), from the client's perspective the API could be called like

```
PATCH /authors/{authorId}/book
[
    { "op": "replace", "path": "/dashboard/content_detail/5", "value": "test"},
    { "op": "remove", "path": "/dashboard/content_detail", "value": [ "7", "9" ]}
]
```

Comment: The HTTP methods PATCH can be used to update partial resources, so it is not the right choice
http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/patch/

Comment: HI, thanks both of you for the input, yes i did try to look up for patch but unfortunately as Trosten said it can only update partial resources. therefore I assume the best way was to submit the the request by separate url would be best

Answer (score 0):

From a design perspective you don't want several ids in your url.

I would prefer single calls for each change, thinking in resources you only manipulate one at a time.

In case this is a perfomance issue, I recommend a special url marked with action or something simliar, to make clear this ist not REST.

Comment: but in my application its a requirement for example if we have to change 30 project status from "In progress" to "complete" single call is not an option

Answer (score 0):

In HTTP it is not required for information to only exist on a single resource. It is possible to have multiple resources that represent the same underlying data.

It's therefore not out of the question to create a resource that 'represents' a set of other resources that you wish to DELETE or PUT to.

I do agree that it might not be the most desirable. I think we tend to prefer having information only exist in a single part of tree, and I think we like to avoid situations where updating a resource effects a secondary resource's state. However, if you are looking for a strictly RESTful solution to solve this problem, I think it's the right way.

Therefore a url design such as:

```
/dashboard/content_detail/5,7,9/
```

Is not necessarily non-RESTful or goes against the HTTP protocol. The fact that you're getting a 404 on that URL currently has to do with your application framework, not the protocol (HTTP) or architecture (REST) of your API.

However, for cases such as these I feel I would personally be inclined to sometimes create a separate `POST` endpoint that, acting outside of REST like an RPC endpoint. Specifically for these types of batch requests.